# Discrepancy in datasheet for AM26LV31E?

Tags: datasheet, differential

The [AM26LV31E datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26lv31e.pdf), a differential line driver, states this (on page 4):

[image: recommended operating conditions]

and this (on page 10):

[image: overview]

At best, this seems ambiguous and, at worst, contradictory. Is the logic of this statement (8.1) clear to any of you?

Comment: I must admit I don't see how it's contradictionary?

Comment: Looks like typical TI behavior to me

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was afraid of that... it did cross my mind that it might just be me. In 6.3 it states that +/- 30 mA is a max (recommended), while in 8.1 it uses the word min. That trips me up.

Comment: Maybe it would have made more sense to me if it were "...to handles loads, **at** a minimum, of +/- 30 mA", instead of "...to handles loads **of** a minimum...". The former implies that it has to handle at least 30 mA, where the later implies that the chip doesn't work properly for loads less than 30 mA. Separating the clause with commas, and changing "of" to "at" seems to makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is clear, though it may be confusing to a user of the chip.

Let's put it this way. The wording of section 8.1 is from the viewpoint of the *designer* of the chip. It says that "the maximum tolerable current must be ±30mA or greater" -- in other words if the chip can tolerate exactly ±30mA, then mission accomplished. If it can accomplish more than that, well that's cool too.

Table 6.3 is from the viewpoint of the *user* of the chip. If you have a chip whose maximum tolerable current is guaranteed to be ±30mA, but in practice it could be even higher than that, then what's your recommended operating current? Well, to be safe you'd better make sure it never exceeds that ±30mA.

In the end it's just a bit of semantics.